# Liferay 7 JSF actions not triggered

Tags: jsf, liferay

I have a liferay portlet application written in JSF 2 Richfaces deployed under weblogic.

Pages are rendered fine, and it seems that EL resolver does it's job well.

However as soon as I initiate any kind of submit the page simply reloads and nothing happens.

I've found several solutions on the Internet, most of them came down to this solution:

[Why isn't Liferay Faces processing JSF portlet action events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194106/why-isnt-liferay-faces-processing-jsf-portlet-action-events)

I've also found these `liferay-porlet.xml` settings in Liferay's official JSF richfaces showcase application so I've already tried them.

The problem is that as soon as I add:

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

To my `liferay-porlet.xml` the portlets become invisible so I can't verify if it fixes the issue.

Has anyone came across a similar issue? Does anyone have any suggestions? I've also looked in to suggestions made in this post:

[action method is not called in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043789/action-method-is-not-called-in-jsf)

None of them appear to apply to my case. I've stripped down my application to the bone. It seems like a Liferay issue.

Versions used:

```
Liferay 7.0
RichFaces 4.5.17
com.liferay.faces.bridge.impl 4.1.1
com.liferay.faces.bridge.ext 5.0.2
com.liferay.faces.bridge.api 4.1.0
javax.faces 2.2.14
```

Comment: I know PrimeFaces had a similar issue and they added some explicit code in the javascript to add the 'portlet namespace' when submitting actions.  Might be related in the fact that RichFaces never implemented this... (just guessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Add the following to your **`WEB-INF/web.xml`** file to ensure that JSF handles namespaced parameters correctly:

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.namespaceParameters</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```

  Some component libraries may not be able to handle namespaced parameters, but I'm pretty sure that PrimeFaces, IceFaces, and RichFaces can (probably BootsFaces and ButterFaces too).
- Add the following to the `<portlet>` section of your **`WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml`**:

  ```
  <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
  ```

It seems like you tried #2, but you may have included the config in the wrong place. That is likely causing an error which in turn causes your portlet to fail to deploy. Check the DTD to ensure that your config is in the right order: https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.0-latest/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_7_0_0.dtd.html

Comment: The issue turned out to be something a bit more weird, regardless adding <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters> did seem to solve my issue.

Comment: However when trying to edit preferences for my portlet i am facing an issue again: 
https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/110225793?_com_liferay_message_boards_web_portlet_MBPortlet_showBreadcrumb=false

Comment: Any change you can help?