# valueChangeListener in selectOneMenu not being called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have an environment where I use Liferay 6.2, Richfaces 4.3.2.Final, JSF 2.1
I am doing exactly what is in the rich face documentation

```
<rich:panelMenu>
   <h:selectOneMenu id="id"  valueChangeListener="#{bean.method}" style="background-color: white">
        <f:selectItems  value="#{bean.getList}"/>
           <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="mainPanel" execute="@this"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
</rich:panelMenu>
```

but the bean are not receiving the event, nothing happen, no erros, no warn, just is not called the "method" in the bean.
I tried already to change the event to "change" instead "valueChange".
the method signature is

```
public void method (ValueChangeEvent event)}
```

Comment: So it works when you remove the `<rich:panelMenu>` wrapper?

Comment: The select definitely doesn't belong inside `rich:panelMenu`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Also did not work taking out of panelMenu I tried like that

`<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="mapType2" valueChangeListener="# {bean.method}"   style="background-color: white">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.list}" />
 <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="mainPanel" execute="@this" /></h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>`

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue with RichFaces `4.3.2.Final`, `4.5.17.Final`, or [`4.6.9.ayg`](https://github.com/albfernandez/richfaces) (which is the version you should update to in order to avoid [RCE security vulnerabilities](https://codewhitesec.blogspot.com/2018/05/poor-richfaces.html)). Please also make sure you are using the correct Liferay Faces dependencies listed here: https://faces.liferay.dev/home/-/archetype-portlet/liferay-portal-version/6.2/jsf-version/2.1/component-suite/jsf/build-tool/maven.

Comment: Also your usage of `rich:panelMenu` differs significantly from the [`rich:panelMenu` documentation](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=panelMenu&skin=wine). I think this usage may be invalid. Finally, please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Hi 
I found out the problem, in the end, was some configuration in the liferay-portlet.xml, I dont know yet which one, but I got a "default" version from this file and now it is working.
My guess is that there is to do with this property <ajaxable>false</ajaxable>, but I will check.

Comment: Hi I found out the problem, in the end, was some configuration in the liferay-portlet.xml, I don't know yet which one, but I got a "default" version from this file and now it is working. My guess is that there is to do with this property <ajaxable>false</ajaxable>, but I will check.

Comment: You probably needed `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>` in your **`liferay-portlet.xml`**.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838124/liferay-7-jsf-actions-not-triggered

Comment: @BhargavRao: What answer? I don't see any comment that looks like an answer

Comment: Sorry bout that @Kukeltje, I must have converted the entire post here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57182854/revisions to comments, instead of just the answer.

Comment: @Kukeltje, I believe [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079584/valuechangelistener-in-selectonemenu-not-being-called#comment100875949_57079584) was the answer.